# R console output alignment

Tags: r, console

My R console window suddenly seems weird. The output is not aligned as usual. Here is the snapshot:
[image]

Does anyone know what's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you're using a proportional width font instead of a fixed width font. Have you changed your font settings?

Comment: What OS are you using and is this straight from the R GUI?

Comment: I was trying to amplify font using "command" + "+", then the alignment of R output become mess. My system is OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: Great! Feel free to write up your solution as an answer in case anyone else comes across a similar problem and searches here.

Comment: If this is something that occurs in RStudio you should  file a bug report. It doesn't happen in the Mac GUI. (My OSX is 10.8.5)